# Rendering Rotated Images

Tags: java, rotation, graphics2d

Why is the following code not rendering the image at an angle.
(I want the image to be rendered on an anchored point on the image). I think that it is rotating around the screen. How can I fix this?

```
public void drawWeapon(Graphics2D g) {
    int iconSize = main.SOutput.iconSize;
    int ePosX =(int) (getPosX() * iconSize 
                - (int) main.player.getPosX() *iconSize)/iconSize;
    int ePosY =(int) (getPosY() * iconSize 
                - (int) main.player.getPosY() *iconSize)/iconSize;

    int PosX = ePosX + (main.SOutput.resX/2)*iconSize 
                + main.SOutput.xPaddingSide;
    int PosY = ePosY + (main.SOutput.resY/2)*iconSize 
                - getImageSizeY()*iconSize;

    if (inventory[0][main.gui.itemSelected] != null){
    g.rotate(facingLeft?scincePressed:-scincePressed);
    g.drawImage(inventory[0][main.gui.itemSelected].item.getImage(), 
                 PosX + (facingLeft?0:getImageSizeX() * iconSize/2), PosY +
                 (getImageSizeY() * iconSize/2), getImageSizeX() * iconSize/2,
                 getImageSizeY() * iconSize/3, null);
    g.rotate(facingLeft?-scincePressed:scincePressed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use this way of working:

1. Push the matrix
2. Translate to the point of rotation
3. Rotate
4. Render at (0, 0)
5. Pop matrix

In code, it would be:

```
AffineTransform matrix = g.getTransform();
g.translate(originX, originY);
g.rotate(angle);
g.drawImage(0, 0, ...);
g.setTransform(matrix);
```

You might also try [`Graphics2D.rotate(theta, originX, originY);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate%28double,%20double,%20double%29)